# People listage in SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

i have an intranet (which is my main website) and a several sub-websites, which refers to the departments of the company. I need to add a list with people related to department of the current web-site. The list can be the same view of the SharePoint native search.

[image]
I find this component (Search Results), which i was able to add my criterias (like people which department is equals to "HR"), and i get the right results. However, i couldn't find an way to make the view similar to the results of the image above.

Somebody can help me? Thanks

Edit:

I've changed the configurations to use "People Item" display index. Firstly, i had to import a javascript file. Then, even though that i had the right results, the properties aren't filled in the fields of the display item (as is shown in the image below).

[image]

Comment: @Eduado Use display templates to modify your search results in intended UI.

Comment: In addition to @vaibhav's comment: Use the 'People Item' display template.